# Spectre V2 on Linux

Tags: ubuntu, security

I have a 64Bit PC Running Ubuntu. The processor (AMD E1-1200) did not receive microcode updates for Spectre protection. What is the best strategy to stay secure? How do you treat the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Unix.SE. Could you [edit] your question to clarify which CPU you have, and also install `spectre-meltdown-checker` (`sudo apt install spectre-meltdown-checker`) and show the output of `sudo spectre-meltdown-checker`?

Comment: I am using AMD E1-1200 processor which unfortunately does not get any microcode updates. I do not know how SUSE is treating this issue - changing the OS would be also an alternative to me.

Comment: Could you show the results of `spectre-meltdown-checker`?

Comment: I had a HDD crash newly and do not know if it is worth buying a new one or just replace the whole PC...

Comment: Show the results of the checker and we’ll be able to tell you.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not use the checker because my PC had a HDD crash and I do not know what to do whith it: is it worth replacing the HDD or better to replace the PC completely...

Answer (score 1):

Install Ubuntu's "intel-microcode" package, and reboot.  This will take care of Intel-based "X86/X86-64" PCs.

Install Ubuntu's "amd64-microcode" package, and reboot.  This will take care of AMD-based "X86-64" PCs.

You need the latest version of the above, which is available on currently-supported LTS. Otherwise, the microcode update package might not have the latest Intel/AMD updates.

Comment: The E1-1200 is a Family 14h CPU, and those haven’t had any micro-code updates since October 2013 (this particular CPU hasn’t been updated since [February 2013](https://www.amd.com/system/files/TechDocs/47534_14h_Mod_00h-0Fh_Rev_Guide.pdf)), so installing and/or upgrading the `amd64-microcode` package won’t help address any Spectre issues.

Comment: That means I must dipose of the PC?